# Why are calendar events spontaneously appearing in my phone, or Is My Phone Haunted?

Tags: sync, calendar

Today my phone beeped during class reminding me of an event I never added to my calendar. It said, 'Jason 2/24/16'. Later today I have another event which I never added, 'Jason 2/24/16 3:30p'. Tomorrow I have an event (also never added myself), 'Jason 2/25/16 10-11a'. A few weeks ago I encountered a similar phenomena, but there was also another name used for a few events, 'Lindsay'. I deleted these old events, but I can post screenshots of the recent ones if anyone needs 'proof'. I say this because I expect some skepticism due to the circumstances of this situation.

What I am looking for is an explanation. There are some things to consider:

- My phone is always on my person and is protected by a password, so it's nigh impossible for someone to have added the calendar events directly with the phone.
- My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4 (carrier Verizon), and the built-in calendar application (I believe its Samsung's own software) syncs with Google calendar. Checking my Google calendar shows none of these Jason or Lindsay events. So the events were not synced up, and they were added to the phone calendar somehow.
- I don't use any apps that to my knowledge would affect the calendar, though I imagine there are some that have the ability to add to the calendar.
- I have no friends or acquaintances named Jason or Lindsay.
- After this happened the first time, I checked through the next ten weeks or so to make sure there were no more of these types of events. The last time I checked was probably a few days ago. So the events appeared recently.
- Looking up Jason and Lindsay I found the Jenner Double-Murder case. I have no involvement in that case and knew nobody involved. For what it's worth, I live in California. The prospect of some connexion scares me.

I have three hypothetical explanations:

1. Some wayward app is adding events and is either doing this as an easter egg prank or just some bug or something like that.
2. Someone is somehow able to access my phone indirectly and is adding these calendar events. Who or why is unknown.
3. My phone is haunted or has a demon in it.

Comment: Sounds like an account that's added on your phone is logged in somewhere else, where someone is creating the events. Do you share a common computer with anyone where this may be happening?

Comment: Change your Google account's password and delete the events

Comment: I have two Google accounts on the phone. I checked both and they have not been accessed by any other devices besides mine. I also have two-step verification for both accounts.

Comment: This could be as mundane as someone invited to you a meeting incorrectly, perhaps they invited the wrong Gmail address? Look at the calendar entry and see who the Organizer is

Comment: Check your google calendars to see if your calendar is being shared to other people.

Comment: I think it is either [ley lines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line) or aliens. There is the highly unlikely possibility that someone just has access to your calendar. Sadly this question is also off-topic for SU as it doesn't involve computers.

Comment: I don't believe the top comments that was made in 2016 by these other people
I believe that there is something definitely wrong with this picture no one can never access to no one calendars or even email addresses.. This is a very good question that no one can really answer but I believe that there is an attachment to that phone from the past somehow.. Do some research on those specific dates and the name of those people from a possible past on those very same days.